# Insert page break into google document in insertText()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm making a document merge with google apps script and I want to guarantee that each new 'page' will be on an actual new page.

I recognize that I could use some sort of for loop and `appendParagraph(text).appendPageBreak()` but, this could be a 100-200 page merge and it seemed very slow and inefficient.

What I'd like to do is just have one `.editAsText().setText(text)` and be able to just call it once with a huge string and be done. But, the page break seemed difficult and I didn't want to have to dynamically calculate the needed new lines/etc

Is there a way to insert page breaks into plain text?

Answer (score 2):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) shows, there's actually a special escape character (á la `\n`) for page break.

It's `\f` and it works perfectly. Adding that puts the next line on a new page.

Comment: also it works perfectly with Edit / Find-Replace `\f` with regex if you need to remove page break from document