# How to insert Page Break to google document by PHP code

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to add PageBreak after Some Text in Google Docs API PHP. 
I got reference [Insert page break into google document in insertText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042999/insert-page-break-into-google-document-in-inserttext), that \f will add page break; But it is not working for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Is there an error message? Result?

Comment: Finally i Got my Answer after a long Research.
Google PHP API CLIENT for Google Docs is still under development. In GitHub Repo https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/v0.93/src/Google/Service/Docs , you will see that in Tag 0.93 Branch There is class for InsertPageBreakRequest in batchUpdate, and still not merge with master Branch. Clone tag v0.93 Repo and get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i Got my Answer after a long Research.
Google PHP API CLIENT for Google Docs is still under development. In GitHub Repo https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/v0.93/src/Google/Service/Docs , you will see that in Tag 0.93 Branch There is class for InsertPageBreakRequest in batchUpdate, and still not merge with master Branch. Clone tag v0.93 Repo and get it done.